# Android Widget textView doesn't update

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm having difficulties with developing an `onclick` widget textView update. Here is the code:

```
remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {

try {
     tytuly = intent.getStringArrayExtra("tytuly");
         contenty = intent.getStringArrayExtra("contenty");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
    }
    String countwrite = Integer.toString(i);
    Toast.makeText(context, countwrite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "asdasd");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, "sdv cxadsa");


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

}
```

`Onclick` action itself works because when I remove `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);` Toast pops out.

`remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "asdasd");` This is right too because I use it in different part of code and everything works. Same `remoteViews` and `thisWidget` declarations.

Why doesn't the  textView widget update?